# Plotly Heatmap Default scale

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am trying to set a default scale for a plotly heatmap. I have gone through the api and they say it should be laid out like the following:

```
const layout = {
    xaxis: {
      title: 'Blade',
      exponentformat: 'none'
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: 'Time',
      exponentformat: 'none'
    },
    geo: {
      projection: {
        scale: 10
      }
    }
  }
```

The `geo.projection.scale` is the key here. Has anyone ever done this before and if so how did you achieve it? At the moment my heatmap is not zooming in.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the answer. Maybe this will come in handy for someone. On the Plotly docs [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-range) it mentions setting an x axis range. I set the first point to the x axis value in my dataset and picked another axis to end with.